# Prolog implement and/2, or/2, nand/2, nor/2, xor/2

Tags: prolog, implementation, xor, clpb, nor

I want to implement the following predicates in prolog and use them for truth-tables: and/2, or/2, nand/2, nor/2, xor/2

Maybe someone can show me how to implement and/2 for example so I can do the others myself and post them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware: You probably mean `and/3`, instead of `and/2`. AND is a ternary predicate, defining a relation between **3** truth values, not 2. Of course, instead of reifying (= making things explicit), you could use Prolog's built-in mechanism, where the truth value is implicit. But to begin, I would start with the ternary relation, since this makes all truth values explicit and lets you also ask for example: "Which truth values yield `false` for a given operation?" To get you started, one entry for the truth table of `and/3`, where I use the atom `true` to denote the Boolean value *true*:

```
and(true, true, true).
```

---

Independently, also consider using Boolean *constraints*, which are for example available in SICStus Prolog and GNU Prolog, and let you declaratively express relations between truth values and Boolean expressions.

Example using `library(clpb)` in SICStus Prolog:

```
| ?- sat(X*Y =:= T), X = 0.
X = 0,
T = 0 ?
```

This shows that if the first argument of a conjunction is false, then the whole conjunction is also false. In addition, we can for example use the CLP(B) solver of SICStus Prolog to determine that conjunction is commutative, using either `taut/2`

```
| ?- taut(A*B =:= B*A, T).
T = 1 ?
```

or universally quantified variables, denoted as *atoms* in `library(clpb)`:

```
| ?- sat(a*b =:= b*a).
yes
```

Thus, Boolean constraints can be very useful tools when working with binary values.

Comment: iam told to implement and/2, or/2

Comment: ? - tafel(A,B,and(A, or(A,B))).  
    true  true  |  true  
    true  fail  |  true  
    fail  true  |  fail  
    fail  fail  |  fail

Comment: You can write down a term like `and(X, Y)` and don't need to implement anything for that: It comes into existence when you write it down. What you *do* need to implement is a predicate that relates such terms to truth values. Start with `expression_truth/2`. An example clause: `expression_truth(true, true).`. Left as an exercise: `expression_truth(and(X,Y), Truth) :- ...`, which relates a term of the form `and(X, Y)` to its truth value.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, i did not made it today but i got an idea and i will try and solve soon. We got plently more stuff to do and this is really time consuming. but thanks

Answer (score 8):

/2 is possible and actually very elegent.

```
and(A,B) :- A,B.
or(A,B) :- A;B.
nand(A,B) :- not(and(A,B)).
nor(A,B) :- not(or(A,B)).
xor(A,B) :- or(A,B), nand(A,B).
```

To use just replace A/B with true/false. For example:

```
?- and(true,true).
true.
?- and(false, true).
false.
```

Comment: With a *binary* relation, where the actual result is implicit in whether the goal succeeds or not, you make it hard to answer the following question that may be important: Which combinations of truth values yield `false`? A *ternary* relation `and/3` makes this very simple and explicit: `?- and(X, Y, false).`. The same goes for the other relations, which are all ternary predicates when you make the truth value explicit so that it is readily accessible in queries.

Comment: I would use a /3 but the question was how to use /2.

Comment: I had to change `or` to `or(A,B) :- A -> true ;B.` (SWI Prolog syntax) to avoid choice point.